# unchecked wpf radio buttons

Tags: wpf, radio-button

I have two radiobuttons.

One (`rb1`) is binded to a property of my `ViewModel`. If the property is true `rb1` is checked when the application is loaded. If the property is false `rb1` is unchecked (that's right).

But in the last case, both radiobuttons are unchecked, and I need the second radiobutton `(rb2)` is checked when property is false. How could I do this??

Comment: So, you have two radio buttons. Are both of these bound to the same property? And when when property value is true, you need rb1 checked and rb2 unchecked and when it is false, you need rb1 unchecked and rb2 checked?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? There was an issue with databinding radio buttons that was fixed in .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are encountering is that the DataBinding is "lost". Let me quote [Matt Thalman](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mthalman/archive/2008/09/04/wpf-data-binding-with-radiobutton.aspx):

> The click would change the UI state of
>   the buttons correctly (for example,
>   clicking Bar would uncheck Foo and
>   check Bar).  But I noticed that if the
>   underlying value of IsFoo and IsBar
>   ever changed after that point, the
>   buttons would not have their IsChecked
>   state updated.  Using the Snoop tool,
>   I discovered that the IsChecked state
>   had had its state set manually after
>   clicking on one of the buttons.  Once
>   a dependency property has been set
>   manually, it loses its Binding.  This
>   is why the IsChecked state was not
>   being changed when the properties
>   being bound to were updated.

A simple solution is to subclass the RadioButton class:

```
public class DataBoundRadioButton : RadioButton
{
     protected override void OnChecked(RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
          // Do nothing. This will prevent IsChecked from being manually set and overwriting the binding.
     }

     protected override void OnToggle()
     {
          // Do nothing. This will prevent IsChecked from being manually set and overwriting the binding.
     }
}
```

See [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mthalman/archive/2008/09/04/wpf-data-binding-with-radiobutton.aspx) for more details.

Comment: AFAIK, this bug was fixed in .NET 4.0 -- you should be able to bind RadioButtons' values without running into this issue now.